# NED vs. SIMBAD: Which is more accurate?

Tags: astronomy, galaxies, data

I'm doing some research on M33.  NED lists the luminosity as 6.27.  SIMBAD gives it as 5.27.  First, it looks odd to me that the difference is exactly 1.  Second, I've seen other differences comparing identical extragalactic bodies, so which database is more reliable?

Comment: Hmm, in the actual [photometry section](http://ned.ipac.caltech.edu/cgi-bin/objsearch?objname=m33&extend=no&hconst=73&omegam=0.27&omegav=0.73&corr_z=1&out_csys=Equatorial&out_equinox=J2000.0&obj_sort=RA+or+Longitude&of=pre_text&zv_breaker=30000.0&list_limit=5&img_stamp=YES#AbsoluteMagnitudeLsun_0) NED lists a V-band magnitude of 5.28. Not sure where the 6.27 comes from.

Comment: Also, can you link to where you see 5.27 in SIMBAD? I see 5.72 (V-band) and 6.27 (B-band) [here](http://simbad.u-strasbg.fr/simbad/sim-basic?Ident=m33&submit=SIMBAD+search).

Comment: Chris, you are correct.  The I had transposed the B and V bands.  NED and SIMBAD agree on the V-Band magnitude.  However, the question stands: which is better?

Answer (score 3):

Neither database is "more reliable" because both draw from a plethora of sources. You can use either to get a rough idea of an object, but beyond that you have to look at what the source of the measurement is (both databases list the publication or other source that reported each measurement).

In your particular example I'd be wary of the luminosity of 6.27 reported by NED. First off, it doesn't even specify a filter. And if you scroll down a bit it explicitly says (under BASIC DATA):

> NOTE: This information is indicative only. With the exception of the
>         redshift they are unreferenced and highly inhomogeneous as to
>         their origin. The Radial Velocity (when available) is computed
>         from the listed redshift. The remaining values are designed to
>         orient the user with a quick-look, overall assessment of the
>         general properties of the object in question. They are not
>         averages nor are they standardized in any way.

But if you continue down to "QUICK LOOK PHOTOMETRY", the values given there seem like what you should be looking at.

For what it's worth, I usually use SIMBAD as I find the interface a bit better, particularly for batch queries, but YMMV. And it's not like I never use NED.

Comment: I *think* the 6.27 is coming from the B-band value [they got from RC3](http://ned.ipac.caltech.edu/cgi-bin/datasearch?search_type=Cat_id&objid=58193&catname=RC3&img_stamp=YES&hconst=73.0&omegam=0.27&omegav=0.73&corr_z=1&of=table), which agrees with the [more primary RC3 source](http://vizier.cfa.harvard.edu/viz-bin/VizieR-4). I suspect whatever discrepancies there are are a combination of mixing up B and V bands and digit switching (note 3RC gives B-V of 0.55, so V would be 5.72, which is what SIMBAD reports and is essentially what NED reports in that band).